# CBC Padding Oracle in SSL3. Why only in SSL3 not in TLS1,TLS1.1, etc

Tags: tls, cbc, openssl, cbc-mac, padding-oracle

I read about PODDLE attack which downgrades the TLS version to SSL 3.0 to exploit CBC padding oracle attack. I looked at the [specs for TLS 1.1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4346.txt)

And found CBC is still used in its ciphersuites. Why is POODLE needs to downgrade to SSL 3? Can't the POODLE attack works by downgrading to TLS 1 or TLS 1.1? Is the CBC implementation in SSL 3 different than that in TLS 1 and TLS 1.1?

Comment: Near dupe http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27856/poodle-attack-on-tls-1-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the reason is that in SSL3 the padding was not specified which was corrected in the specification of TLS. [Here](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/10/14/poodle.html) is a detailed and readable explanation of the attack.

However, there is a [variant of the poodle attack](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/12/08/poodleagain.html) that also works on TLS because the same procedure as for SSL3 could be used on TLS packets. While this was not standard-compliant it would work and some implementations are vulnerable.